# Create multiple shortcuts to subfolders with the same name

Tags: powershell, shortcut

Beginner Here, i PUt together this but cant make it work..
I have multiple folders each of them contain own subfolder ‘zero’ , I’m trying to create shortcuts to each of those subfolders with the name of its parent folder

...

```
$app = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"

$container = "C:\Users\$app = New-Object -ComObject "WScript.Shell"

$container = "C:\Users\Desktop\skty"
$path = "C:\Users\Desktop\fold"

if (!(Test-Path $container)) {
  New-Item -Type Directory -Path $container | Out-Null
}

Get-Childitem -Path $path -Recurse -Include "zero*" | Foreach-Object {

{ $ShortcutFile = "$container\$_.Directory.Parent.Name + $_.Name"
  $app.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
  $Shortcut.TargetPath = $_.FullName
  $Shortcut.Save() 
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started:

This will put a shortcuts on everones Desktop pointing to the users Documents folder.

```
$container = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users

ForEach ($upath in $container){
    $sfilepath = $upath.FullName + "\Documents"
    $scutpath  = $upath.FullName + "\Desktop"

    $SourceFilePath = $sfilepath
    $ShortcutPath = "$scutpath" + "\Documents.lnk"
    $WScriptObj = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
    $shortcut = $WscriptObj.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
    $shortcut.TargetPath = $SourceFilePath
    $shortcut.Save()
}
```

If you know the location you need to use, you can use [Get-Content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-5.1)

Please play with the location to get the output you need.